# How to detect scrolling to another page in PDF using PDFkit

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, pdfkit

I'm trying to add current page number 
so when the user scrolling to another page it will display
for example
2 of 3 (if the pdf have 3 pages)

for now, I use this code

it will display always 1 of 3

I think PDFkit using UIScrollView 
so I need to reach to the ScrollView that way I could detect when scrolling to another page and then increase the current page number

I didn't find any way to reach to scrollview in PDFkit

```
 func showCurrentPageIndex(){

        guard let totalPages = pdfContainerView.document?.pageCount else {return}
        guard let currentPage = pdfContainerView.currentPage else {return}
        guard let currentPageRef = currentPage.pageRef else {return}

let pageIndex = currentPageRef.pageNumber

      totalPageNumbers.text = "\(totalPages)"
      currentPageIndex.text =  "\(pageIndex)"
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a notification (`PDFViewPageChanged`).

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, PDFViewDelegate {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var totalCount = Int()

    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!

    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let filePath = "Some file document path"
        pdfView.document = getDocument(path: filePath)
        if let total = pdfView.document?.pageCount {
            totalCount = total
        }
        pdfView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        /* notification */
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver (self, selector: #selector(handlePageChange), name: Notification.Name.PDFViewPageChanged, object: nil)
    }

    func getDocument(path: String) -> PDFDocument? {
        let pdfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        let document = PDFDocument(url: pdfURL)
        return document
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it working
 
I didn't know there is a notification for page change

just to make your code complete answer
you forget to add handlePageChange function
which is for my case the same function I added showCurrentPageIndex()

also I think you must remove NotificationCenter in viewDidDisappear

   ```override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name.PDFViewPageChanged, object: nil)
    }```